# AttachedProperty is giving me bizarre error: property was already registered by 'button'

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013, designer, attached-properties

I recently upgraded from VS2010 to VS2013, and now I'm getting a strange error on some of my dialogs with an attached property.

```
Error   4   'IsAccept' property was already registered by 'Button'. C:\Projects\... .xaml   9   9   {ProjectName}
```

I have a DialogBehaviors class which has two attached properties: IsAccept and CenterMainWindow. The problem is, whenever I use one, it complains the **other one** is already registered?! This only happens if the View is open in the designer. If no windows are open in the designer, it compiles without any errors.

[image: When applied to a Window, the other attached property gives an error]
[image: Vice versa]
[image: error window]

Here's my attached properties.

```
public static class DialogBehaviors
{
    private static void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Button)sender;

        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(button);
        while (parent != null && !(parent is Window))
        {
            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
        }

        if (parent != null)
        {
            ((Window)parent).DialogResult = true;
        }
    }

    private static void IsAcceptChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Button)obj;
        var enabled = (bool)e.NewValue;

        if (button != null)
        {
            if (enabled)
            {
                button.Click += OnClick;
            }
            else
            {
                button.Click -= OnClick;
            }
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsAcceptProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            name: "IsAccept",
            propertyType: typeof(bool),
            ownerType: typeof(Button),
            defaultMetadata: new UIPropertyMetadata(
                defaultValue: false,
                propertyChangedCallback: IsAcceptChanged));

    public static bool GetIsAccept(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsAcceptProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsAccept(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsAcceptProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CenterMainWindowProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            name: "CenterMainWindow",
            propertyType: typeof(bool),
            ownerType: typeof(Window),
            defaultMetadata: new UIPropertyMetadata(
                defaultValue: false,
                propertyChangedCallback: CenterMainWindowChanged));

    public static bool GetCenterMainWindow(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(CenterMainWindowProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCenterMainWindow(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(CenterMainWindowProperty, value);
    }

    private static void CenterMainWindowChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window window = obj as Window;
        bool enabled = (bool)e.NewValue;

        if (window != null)
        {
            if (enabled)
            {
                window.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
                window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
            }
            else
            {
                window.Owner = null;
                window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't remember this happening before. I've checked and these attached properties are only registered once, in one location, in one assembly. There are not redundant definitions. All the definitions are static as they should be. This error only shows up while the View is open in a VS tab.

Comment: OwnerType for an attached dp isn't supposed to be the type for which you will set it. It is supposed to be the class that defines the dp so it should be DialogBehaviors. Its what the framework will use to get from a dp to the static field for a dp and the get/set methods.

Comment: @AndrewS Ok, thanks, I read the question/answer that was marked duplicate before I created my question but I didn't think it was the same because his was not an attached property and mine was. I changed it and it appears to be working.